# Looping the data structure returned from InfluxDB::HTTP in perl

Tags: perl, influxdb

Trying to get out the value pair in values.

```
my $influx = InfluxDB::HTTP->new(host => 'localhost', port => 8086);
my $query = 'SELECT mean(value) FROM db1.autogen.num1,db1.autogen.num2 WHERE time > now() - 1h GROUP BY time(1s) LIMIT 20';

my $res = $influx->query([$query], epoch => 's',);
print $res;
```

The result I'm getting is this:

```
Returned data: {"results":[{"statement_id":0,"series":[{"name":"num1","columns":["time","value"],"values":[[1550842812,114.098],[1550842812,114.084],[1550842812,114.07],[1550842812,114.055],[1550842812,114.041],[1550842813,114.027],[1550842813,114.012],[1550842813,113.998],[1550842813,113.984],[1550842813,113.969],[1550842814,113.955],[1550842814,113.941],[1550842814,113.926],[1550842814,113.911],[1550842814,113.897],[1550842815,113.883],[1550842815,113.868],[1550842815,113.854],[1550842815,113.84],[1550842815,113.825]]},{"name":"num2","columns":["time"│ ,"value"],"values":[[1550842812,11.358],[1550842812,11.373],[1550842812,11.388],[1550842812,11.402],[1550842812,11.416],[1550842813,11.431],[1550842813,11.445],[1550842813,11.459],[155084│ 2813,11.474],[1550842813,11.488],[1550842814,11.502],[1550842814,11.517],[1550842814,11.531],[1550842814,11.545],[1550842814,11.56],[1550842815,11.575],[1550842815,11.589],[1550842815,11.│ 604],[1550842815,11.618],[1550842815,11.632]]}]}]}
```

But when I do a:

```
print $res->{results};

Object returned by call to InfluxDB::HTTP::query() at test.pl line 10 can't be used as <HASH> at test.pl line 12.
```

So it looks like a hash, but it isn't? Any tips on how to work with the data structure?

https://metacpan.org/pod/InfluxDB::HTTP

Comment: Yes, the documentation says that the data element is a hash if the query was successful.

Comment: fyi: removed my comments on hashes/objects etc (it's all in the answers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation has a section entitled [Return Values and Error Handling](https://metacpan.org/pod/InfluxDB::HTTP#RETURN-VALUES-AND-ERROR-HANDLING) which says:

> `Object::Result` is relied upon for returning data from subroutines.

I guess it would be more helpful if that was a link to the [Object::Result](https://metacpan.org/pod/Object::Result) documentation or contained better examples of using the returned object.

But looking at the source code, I see the result object is created like this:

```
result {
    raw         { return $response; }
    data        { return $data; }
    results     { return $data->{results}; }
    request_id  { return $response->header('Request-Id'); }
    <STR>       { return "Returned data: $content"; }
    <BOOL>      { return 1; }
}
```

From which I guess, you can get the actual data that you want from `$res->data` or `$res->results` - both of which will return hash references. Or if you want the raw query response, you can use `$res->raw`.

I think that the values data you want is `$res->results->[0]{series}[0]{values}`.

Oh, and later on, the documentation for the `query()` method says:

> If the returned object evaluates to true, indicating that the query was successful, then the returned object's `data` attribute contains the entire response from InfluxDB as Perl hash. Additionally the attribute `request_id` provides the request identifier as set in the HTTP reponse headers by InfluxDB. This can for example be useful for correlating requests with log files.

Doesn't mention the `results` attribute though.

Comment: You are right. I needed the array index as well. I think the documentation could have been a little more comprehensive. A couple of examples would have been nice.

Comment: I also found docs to leave things to be desired.  One particular gripe: I don't see a point in docs telling me how the returned object's attribute (of a different class) is kept (as a hash) -- that's preciseley what is meant to be "hidden" (in OO) !!  Or, to not matter at least. They may want to tell me how to retrieve results though, but they don't.

Answer (score 1):

`Object returned by call to InfluxDB::HTTP::query() ... can't be used as <HASH>` is a clue that `$res` is an object. [Consult the relevant API](https://metacpan.org/pod/InfluxDB::HTTP#RETURN-VALUES-AND-ERROR-HANDLING) to see what operations are allowed on the object to access its data.

Comment: I did, and it said, "If the returned object evaluates to true, indicating that the query was successful, then the returned object's data attribute contains the entire response from InfluxDB as Perl hash." And when I tried using the data attribute as a hash, I got the "can't be used as a hash" error. That was somewhat confusing.